# Dojo pie chart - want to display the data array values as it is

Tags: dojo

I am working on dojo pie chart. When I feed data to the chart as
[ {y:10}, {y:40}, {y:30}]
I want to see the values displayed on the chart as 10%, 40% and 30%. But the chart displays as 12.5%, 37.5% and 50%. What should I do, to enable the pie chart display the values, which I send as it is?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple: set labels as you want them: `[{y: 10, text: "10%"}, ...]` and so on. You can easily automate it. A sketch:

```
var items = [10, 40, 30];
addSeries("default", dojo.map(values, function(item){
  return {y: item, text: item + "%"};
});
```

The same way you can add custom tooltips, or some other attributes (e.g., colors).